# Knockout JS - you cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element - MVC

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am new to knockout js and dont understand why i am getting this error.

I have a view in .net mvc that when a button is clicked uses jquery to query the database with ajax and then returns data, then i pass it to knockout to render, when you click on the button it opens a modal window and displays the data fine, but it only does it once, every second time and time after it displays the multiple elements error.

Any ideas?

```
 var ViewModel = function (docs) {

  this.docs = ko.observable(docs);

};

$('.js--click').click(function () {

    var id = $(this).data('id');

        $.post("GetData", { id: id })
           .done(function (data) {

             ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data.docs));
    });
});


<div data-bind="if: docs()">
<span data-bind="text: docs></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like the error message says: you can only call `ko.applyBindings` once on the same element. You just want to update an observable on your view model; this isn't the way to do that.

The standard way of doing things with Knockout is that you would have a function on your view model that gets the data, then updates an observable with this new data, and then the UI will sync automatically. You would use the standard KO `click` handler to attach the click event to a button, rather than use jQuery.

Going with your example, you'd have to do something along these lines:

```
function ViewModel () {
    var vm = this;

    vm.docs = ko.observable();

    vm.getData = function (id) {
        $.post("GetData", { id: id })
         .done(function (data) {
            vm.docs(data.docs);
    });
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); // We only do this once!


<button data-bind="click: getData.bind($data, 'myID')"></button>

<div data-bind="if: docs">
    <span data-bind="text: docs"></span>
</div>
```